# Perl CGI - Picking Radio Values for Specificity

Tags: html, perl

I've got a little Perl CGI quiz that I am working on, but I'm completely stuck on it. My HTML code is as follows:

```html
<p class="question"><br>1. The answer is Number 1 </p>
<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">1912</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">1922</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">1925</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label            for="q1d">Summer of '69</label><br/>
</ul>
```

The CGI program is picking the name from the radio button for its parameter value. My Perl code is as follows:

```
if ( param("q1") eq undef ) {
    $an1 = 0;
    $winner = 0;
print <<"BIG";
        <h1>You didn't enter the right answer</h1>
BIG
}
else {
print <<"BIG";
        <h1>You entered the right answer</h1>
BIG
}
```

At this point, it will say I entered the right answer if I check any of the radio boxes.

Is there some way I can specify which value it plucks from radio, like `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` for the parameter, or am I doing it wrong altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Please, refer to [CGI documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#CREATING-A-RADIO-BUTTON-GROUP) for details on how to process radio group.
To give you an example:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $value = $cgi->param('q1');

if ($value eq 'a') { #correct answer

}
else { # incorrect answer
}
```

Also, `eq` is a string comparison operator, don't use it to test for `undef`. Perl has a `defined` function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program. With those in place you would have seen the message `Use of uninitialized value in string eq`

You can't compare a value to `undef` using the string comparator `eq`. In your case, `param("q1")` will be `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`, or perhaps `undef` if none of the radio buttons are selected. (You would generally make one of the radio buttons selected by default to avoid this, using `checked="checked"`.)

Here's a basic CGI program that works fine.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use CGI::Minimal;
use File::Spec::Functions 'abs2rel';

my $self = abs2rel($0, $ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT});

my $cgi = CGI::Minimal->new;

my $q1 = $cgi->param('q1') // 'none';

my $message = 
        ($q1 eq 'a') ?    "<h3>You entered the right answer</h3>" :
        ($q1 ne 'none') ? "<h3>You didn't enter the right answer</h3>" :
        '';

print <<END;
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="$self">

            <p class="question"><br/>
            1. The answer is Number 1
            </p>

            <ul class="answers">

                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="none" id="q1a" checked="checked" />
                <label for="q1a"><i>Please choose an answer</i></label>
                <br/>

                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" />
                <label for="q1a">1912</label>
                <br/>

                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b" />
                <label for="q1b">1922</label>
                <br/>

                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" />
                <label for="q1c">1925</label>
                <br/>

                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d" />
                <label for="q1d">Summer of '69</label>
                <br/>
            </ul>

            <input type="submit">

        </form>

        $message

    </body>
</html>

END
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
$radio_value = $cgi->param('q1')
```

also after closing html tag with BIG it seems that it is not ending because its steel red!you write that lines with print!

Comment: The Stack Overflow syntax highlighter is not very smart with Perl. But you're right, there should be empty lines after the HEREDOC delimiter.